# Electrical gfci breaker

Tags: electrical, gfci

I installed a gfci breaker with black-red-white wires with no ground and it trips. Found the problem and the neutral is supplying two circuits in the same cable. Is my only remedy to run neutral for each circuit

Comment: Sounds like a multi-wire branch circuit. What model of GFCI breaker has black, red, and white wires?

Comment: From what I read on here, a GFCI breaker is the proper choice for a MWBC.  It is the GFCI receptacles that do not work on those circuits.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and use the 'sun & mountains' add a pic or 3 of your new breaker installation.

Comment: Did you install a single-pole breaker and put black and red on the same screw?

Comment: @crip659 a GFCI receptacle works fine on a MWBC by itself, you just can't use it to feed anything downstream on the shared neutral.

Comment: @KMJ  Bad wording on my part.  There does seem to be more wiring problems/people not wiring them right, and breakers make stuff simple.  As you said there is one right way.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to use a two-pole GFCI breaker, so that the the black line, red line, and neutral white all connect to the *same* breaker. The breaker pigtail or PON connection then connects to the neutral at the panel.

If you did that, there's another problem such as a neutral being shared with another circuit, or shorted to ground which you'll need to find and solve.

If you didn't do that; (it's not at all clear what you did do, from your question) do that, it will solve the problem for a *correctly wired* Multi-Wire Branch Circuit.

The other alternative solution is to make each (and every) receptacle a GFCI where each one is connected only to black and white, or only to red and white, and you would aim to have half on red & white and half on black & white - use only the "Line" terminals on the GFCIs, and connect the unused hot color separately to pass power on to the next device.